# Observable `of` deprecated. What is the equivalent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In my case, I have an access token, and should that token exist, I would return it as an observable of type string:

```
if (this.accessToken){
  return of(this.accessToken);
}
```

Due to a recent update, I noticed that `of` is deprecated with the following message:

`of is deprecated: use scheduled instead 'scheduled([a, b, c], scheduler)' (deprecation)`

The new syntax is quite verbose,  would anyone know the equivalent `scheduled` version of the same simple `of`?  The keyword name makes it difficult to search for information on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You must have imported the wrong `of`. Check your import statements ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Only the overloads that accept a scheduler are deprecated. The variant that you are using is not deprecated, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/of.ts

Answer (score 15):

As said above, it is not deprecated.

I suppose you are migrating from RxJS **v5** to RxJS **v6**. In that case:

The standard observable processing like of, map, filter, etc

```js
Observable.of(1,2,3).map(x => 2 * x);
```

**Becomes**

```js
import {of, map} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1,2,3).pipe(map(x => 2 * x));
```

Check more here https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/rxjs5-6.html

Answer (score 6):

@daniel-hilgarth is right but you can use following commands if you need to emulate `of(1, 2, 3)`

```
import {asapScheduler, scheduled} from "rxjs";
scheduled([1, 2, 3], asapScheduler);
```

or

```
import {asyncScheduler, scheduled} from "rxjs";
scheduled([1, 2, 3], asyncScheduler);
```

You can read more about asap here: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asapScheduler

Answer (score 5):

If you do have a scheduler, the equivalent for `of(item, scheduler)` is `scheduled([item], scheduler)`. If you're already passing in an array of items, you don't need the brackets.

Answer (score -3):

You need to import correctly. I give the following example for your reference.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-type':  'application/json'
  })
};

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, httpOptions).pipe(map((response : any) => {
const user = response.json();
if (user.accessToken){
  localStorage.setItem('token', user.accessToken);
  return user.accessToken;
} }))
```